Identification of SOT-23 on Fluke 175


I have been trying to repair my Fluke 175. The board is FLUKE 17X-3021 REV 004.
I was told to desolder these two SOT-23s and they broke on me when I did. They might have been already broken. I can't for the life of me figure out what they are.
Sorry the top one is a bit hard to read, but this is the only good picture of them. Hopefully someone here can help.

After spending all day trying to figure it out my best guess is the M1L is NSVMMBT6429LT1G

And the CXQPI one is a IRLML6302 from looking at this

Let me know what you guys think. Did I do alright?

You identified the parts correctly. You should post this as an answer and not edit it into the question. You can then accept your own answer.

I think you are correct, you can answer yourself below and accept it.

M1L is NSVMMBT6429LT1G and the
CXQPI one is a IRLML6302
